# Install a Android Library into local Maven Repo

Tags: android, maven, android-holo-everywhere

I am trying to use [HoloEverywhere 1.3.2](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) in my android project and I am using Maven to build the project. The latest version of HoloEverywhere in Maven Central is 1.2.0.

Authors of HoloEverywhere are in the process of pushing the latest version of library to the Maven Central in the mean time I wish to install the library to my local Maven Repo.

**My Question**

How to install a Android Library (HoloEverywhere) to local Maven Repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So download source code and execute `mvn clean install`.

From the http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/

> The Install Plugin is used during the install phase to add artifact(s) to the local repository. The Install Plugin uses the information in the POM (groupId, artifactId, version) to determine the proper location for the artifact within the local repository.
>
> The local repository is the local cache where all artifacts needed for the build are stored. By default, it is located within the user's home directory (~/.m2/repository) but the location can be configured in ~/.m2/settings.xml using the  element.

Comment: This does not install HoloEverywhere to local Maven repo. (.m2 folder in user in Windows 7 OS) It just builds the library.

Comment: For just building there is `package` command. Check your `settings.xml` file.

Comment: Looks like "Install Plugin" and "install" are different. There is no settings file in ~/m2.

Comment: `install` is the `goal` of Install plugin. It is ok not having settings.xml.

Comment: So the problem still remains, I could not install HoloEverywhere 1.3.2 to local Maven Repo.

Comment: Do you get any errors running `install`? Try `mvn insall -e` for debug output.

Comment: No errors. The build was successful but it was installed to local repo.

Comment: You mean was NOT installed? Could you put maven output to your question?

Comment: The output is too big to added to question, please have a look at this file...http://www.mediafire.com/?m247oczd2q4ic6f

Comment: So you are saying folder C:\
Users\abc\.m2\repository\com\github\christopheversieux\holoeverywhere-parent\
1.3.1-SNAPSHOT\ is empty after executing `mvn install` ?

Comment: Maven log shows it is installed successfully at here `C:\Users\abc\.m2\repository\
com\github\christopheversieux\holoeverywhere-library\1.3.1-SNAPSHOT\holoeverywhere-library-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT.apklib`, please double check.

Comment: No, it is not. Thanks so much for your time and patience.